# Insert data in DB from textbox that is associated from another table

Tags: c#, sql

I have a application that is used to pull random drug screening for employees. I need to be able to enter an employee manually as well. The problem I am having is that I do not know how to do that with the way their DB is set up. It is set up with a TEST table that has the employee ID, Selection Date, Test Reason (example: 10). The employee ID is located in an employee table and the test reason is in a testreason table.  My form has a place to enter the employee first name, last name, and the reason for the test. They need to be all entered into the Test table.

```
private void SubmitBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\Med Trac\MedTrac.accdb;
                            Persist Security Info=False";
        try
        {
            string cmdstring = "INSERT INTO Test (SELECTION_DATE) VALUES(@date);";
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstring, con))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Submitted Successfully");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed due to " + ex.Message);
        }

    }`
```

That is all I have been able to get to work so far. Any help would be great.

Comment: What is the exact problem then? Is it that you want to insert into Table employee and Table Test at the same time and you don't know how to do, or what??

Comment: I need to post to Test table but in that table the employee is an ID number not a name and the test reason is a number not a description. In my form I have a textbox for the name of the employee and a combo box for the test reasons that are available.

Comment: Post the Schema for Test and TestReason Tables.

Comment: What problems are you facing in inserting data into Table Test? @user3538446

Comment: I do not know how to convert the user input of name "Bob", for example, into the employee ID "12345". That is stored in Employee table. I need the id "12345" stored in the test table with the selection date that I have working in the code above.